# Markov Inequality example confusion

Tags: probability, markov-chains, upper-lower-bounds

Basic q I'm sure. Markov's inequality states that the upper bound to the probability that the realization of a random variable exceeds a given threshold is defined thus:
$P(|X| \ge c) \le \frac{E[X]}{c}$

so if E[X] is 100 and c is 150 I get a probability of $\frac{100}{150}$ = 0.66

No problem so far. However, if E[X] = 100 and c = 50, I get a probability of $\frac{100}{50}$ = 2

which is obviously wrong. Most examples online have a c value greater the the expected value. Can someone clarify please?

Comment: It is a true statement to say $P(|X| \ge 50) \le 2$ since no probability can exceed $1$.  True but not very useful.

Comment: Incidentally you can either state Markov's inequality as $P(X \ge c) \le \frac{E[X]}{c}$ for a non-negative random variable $X$ or as  $P(|X| \ge c) \le \frac{E[|X|]}{c}$ more generally (assuming these expectations are finite and $c$ is positive) but not quite as you have stated it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I get a probability of 2 which is obviously wrong

Markov inequality does not give a probability but a bound. And $P(\text{something})\le 2 $ is not wrong, but, on the contrary always true. Because it's a trivial truth (we already had a better bound: $1$) the bound is in this case (still valid but) useless.

Comment: OK, understood. Then any comment on the usefulness/relevance of Markov's inequality when the value being looked at (the c value) is less than the expected value given that the upper bound identified will always be greater than 1?